# Remove browser autocomplete in my angular application

Tags: html, angular, web, web-applications

I'm creating an angular application where the first screen is a login screen. Once I've logged into the web application I'm asked by the browser if I want to save that user along with their password to auto-enter it in the future when I logout.
I have tried using "autocomplete: 'new-password'" but this does not autocomplete the field, but when I click on it it recommends saved passwords and I don't want that either. I don't want my application to EVER autocomplete fields or save any password under any circumstances.

Comment: Did you try `<input [...] autocomplete="off">` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but I don't get the expected result.

Comment: On an old project, I opted for a random value for autocomplete : `const value = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');`. It makes the browser not understand which value to take and finally not filling it XD